# Map key sequence of more than two keys

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, xdotool

I have created and script that uses xdotool to open new tabs in specific firefox containers. I need to map three keys, for instance *ctrl+y+p* to open a personal container, *ctrl+y+b* to open the banking container and so on. I cannot find a tool that lets you map more than two keys.

Is there something like what I have described?

Thanks a lot.

Edit: For anyone looking for an answer, I found a way. I use i3 so I just added a mode triggered by pressing the first two keys and then mapped the "b" to the command + escape (to exit the mode).

Answer (score 2):

Install xdotool if you haven't already done so, for example:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

As per your example (CTRL+y+p), execute:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xdotool keydown ctrl keydown y keydown p
```

Which presses the three keys but does not release them after. An alternative way:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xdotool key ctrl+y+p
```

:0 is a typical value for the display, but in my Raspberry Pi, for example, it needed to be DISPLAY=:10.  If you are still having trouble with the display variable and get a message like this:

> xdotool can't open display (null)

then you could obtain the display value with:

```
ps -u $(id -u) -o pid= | \
    while read pid; do
        cat /proc/$pid/environ 2>/dev/null | tr '\0' '\n' | grep '^DISPLAY=:'
    done | grep -o ':[0-9]*' | sort -u
```

Another alternative way to obtain DISPLAY values (it will be the number after the ':' )

```
xauth list
```

This works in raspbian too:

```
w -hs | awk '{print $3}' | sort -u | grep -v -
```

Good luck